How should the conjecture associated with Taniyama, Shimura, etc. be referred to?
I'm writing an article in which I need to refer to the Modularity theorem before it was a theorem. I always knew it as the first on the list below, but I'm aware there are alternatives, so I need to choose.
It's not a mathematics article, so my choice is not important in that sense. I simply want to avoid either mis-choosing, if by doing so I inadvertently imply some point or other, or even cause offense. And if there really is no particularly bad or particularly good choice -- i.e. it's a matter of opinion -- that's as useful an answer to me as one of the items on the list, which is as follows:

The Taniyama-Shimura conjecture
The Taniyama-Shimura-Weil conjecture
The Shimura-Taniyama-Weil conjecture

Are they all fine, or are any to be preferred or, contrariwise, avoided?

They're probably all fine, I'd go with 2 if pressed.

You could just call it "the modularity conjecture for elliptic curves".
